# Creating a dictionary from a csv file in Python by using own function

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary, split

I got completely lost in figuring out this problem below. Here is the question:

country_population_data.csv
[how the csv looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3n3d.png)

1. extract only the country name and its population from the csv. file (e.g., 'China', 14442161070)
2. create an empty dictionary named pop_dict. Then read the country_population_data.csv file, as a list of lines.
3. for each line of the records, extract a tuple of country name and population, then store it into the empty dictionary.

*requirement: create own function and use it

The answer should look like:
{'China': 14442161070, 'India': 13934090380,  ...

My first approach was making a function to extract the required items from the csv file as a tuple, but somehow it did not work out and gave me this error.
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

```
#funtion to split items
with open(csv, 'r') as f:
 def str_to_tuple(f)
  str_splitted = tuple(f.split(","))
  result_tuple = str_splitted.str()[1] + str_splitted.int()[-1]
  return(result_tuple)
print(str_to_tuple(f))
```

And I also was not sure how to put extracted values in a new dictionary. Could anyone help me with this question? It has been just a couple of weeks for me to learn python so bear with my poor codes and explanation.

Any feedback & comments & tips are welcome to get used to this python world!

Comment: I would recommend for you starting slow. Do one thing at a time. Make a code that reads a sample text file and prints the lines in the screen. Make another code that given a string splits it. print each step and debug it. Once you have little pieces of code that do one and only one thing start putting them together. Understand what each line does and if not ask for some specific question.

Comment: Looking at your code, you do `with open(csv, 'r') as f:`. What is csv? is the name of the file? if so, it should be "csv". a variable having the filename? then it should have been previously defined and assigned. then you define a function after opening the file, which should be the oposite, you open a file inside a function. Then you do `str_splitted.str()[1]`. What is the `.str()` suposed to do? convert it to an string? if so it should be `str(str_splitted.str()[1])`.  Go line by line and understand what you are trying to do and the syntax you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a question that is part of a course, I will refrain from simply giving you the answer. Instead, I will try to give you some hints, which might help you find the answer by yourself.

My suggestion is that you start with trying to answer the following questions:

1. How should you call a function in Python? Is that how you do it in your script? Hint: probably not ;) If not, how would you fix this?
2. What is the type of `f` (i.e. `print(type(f))` to find out)? Did you expect that to be the type of `f`? Hint: probably not ;)  What do you expect the type of `f` to be? Perhaps we need to call .split(",") on a different variable, one that perhaps doesn't exist yet?